# Excel - Absolute formula for every N row

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, offset, absolute

Column J = Review Frequency (Annually, 6 Monthly, Quarterly, Monthly)

Column L = Last Review Date (i.e.: 01/01/2020)

Column M = Review Due Date

Current formula in column M is:

```
=IF(J3="Annually",DATE(YEAR(L3)+1,MONTH(L3),DAY(L3)),IF(J3="6 Monthly",DATE(YEAR(L3),MONTH(L3)+6,DAY(L3)),IF(J3="Quarterly",DATE(YEAR(L3),MONTH(L3)+3,DAY(L3)),IF(J3="Monthly",DATE(YEAR(L3),MONTH(L3)+1,DAY(L3)),"ERROR"))))
```

The problem is...column J is merged across 7 cells. As soon as I drag the formula in column M down it will just show as "ERROR".

I need to keep the cell fixed on J3 for 7 rows, on the 8th row I need to update the cell reference from J3 to J10.

How do I do this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Formula XLOOKUP:

```
=IFERROR(EDATE(L9,CHOOSE(MATCH(XLOOKUP("*",$J$3:J9,$J$3:J9,,2,-1),{"Annually","6 Monthly","Quarterly","Monthly"},0),12,6,3,1)),"Error")
```

[image]

---

If one does not have the Dynamic Array formula then using INDEX/MATCH():

```
=EDATE(L3,CHOOSE(MATCH(INDEX(J:J,MATCH("zzz",$J$1:J3)),{"Annually","6 Monthly","Quarterly","Monthly"},0),12,6,3,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `indirect` by replacing all your references to `J3` with

```
INDIRECT("J" & FLOOR((ROW(A1)-1)/7, 1)*7 + 3)
```

So your formula becomes

```
=IF(INDIRECT("J" & FLOOR((ROW(A1)-1)/7, 1)*7 + 3)="Annually",DATE(YEAR(L3)+1,MONTH(L3),DAY(L3)),IF(INDIRECT("J" & FLOOR((ROW(A1)-1)/7, 1)*7 + 3)="6 Monthly",...
```

or you can use `choose` like Scott Craner did

```
=IFERROR(EDATE(L9,CHOOSE(INDIRECT("J" & FLOOR((ROW(A1)-1)/7, 1)*7 + 3),{"Annually","6 Monthly","Quarterly","Monthly"},0),12,6,3,1)),"Error")
```

Comment: These are just FYI.  1.  This works if the pattern is always 7 cells merged. 2.  I would use INDEX: `INDEX(J:J,FLOOR((ROW(A8)-1)/7, 1)*7 + 3)` as INDIRECT is Volatile.

Comment: Using the INDIRECT method works great, however, Row 59 is a blank row. When I use the same formula from Row 60 onward I start receiving the ERROR message again. Why is this?

Comment: As scott mentioned in the comment, this method assumes the pattern is always 7 cells merged, no gaps. Also, you should prefer INDEX as per Scott's comment above.